# Powershell CSV Addition

Tags: powershell

I have csv file that contains multiple columns. I am trying sum one of the entire column. But its not giving exact result.

testdisk1.csv

```
Monthcost
12
14
15
```

add.ps1

```
Import-Csv './testdisk1.csv' | Measure-Object "MonthCost" -Sum
```

Comment: Try `(Import-Csv './testdisk1.csv' | Measure-Object "MonthCost" -Sum).Sum`

Comment: @Theo Thanks for your suggestion. How can we add the same total amount in the same csv file

Comment: To understand clearly
Monthcost
12
14
15
Total 41
I need to calculate and save it as total in same excel